# How do i delete selected items in list view with vbyesno

Tags: vba, ms-access

This code is deleting the selected item in `listview` except for some reason it's showing the `response` 2 times and deleting the data twice. It should only appear once to confirm if i want to delete the item that i selected.

```
   Dim response As Integer

    For Each i As ListViewItem In ListView.SelectedItems
        response = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete " + TextBox.Text, vbYesNo, "Confirm Delete")
        If response = vbYes Then
            ListView.Items.Remove(i)
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: What's `TextBox.Text` and how is that related to `ListViewItem`/`i`? Seems like that msgbox should point to `ListView.SelectedItems(i).Text` If that is a thing? (It's been a while since I dealt with a control like this though.

Comment: And, again, I may be way off base here since my memory is foggy on this one, but... You are iterating `ListView.SelectedItems` you then refer in the msgbox to `Textbox.Text` then you delete `ListView.Items` based on the index from `ListView.SelectedItems`. It seems like three somewhat unrelated things happening when everything should be pointing to `ListView.SelectedItems` since that's what you are iterating.

Comment: Basing on @JNevill comment, you iterate over selected items. This just doesn't make a sense. Perhaps, you need to make single selection for ListView rather multiple.

Comment: It may be fine... again because I don't have an environment to test this, but it could be that the index/listviewitem pulled for the `ListView.SelectedItem` refers to the ListViewItem object that can then be referred to directly against the control's `Items` collection. But still the `Textbox.Text` thing is throwing me off. I feel like the issue (being deleted twice) is not really the issue. Two ListViewItems are being deleted. One the correct one, and one an incorrect one since `Textbox.Text` isn't being updated inthe loop. The msgbox is just saying the same twice, but deleting two things.

Comment: its a code i got in the here in stack overflow on how to delete items i select on `listview` the code works but i don't just want the items to be deleted when i click on it, i need it to have a confirmation from the user

Comment: @OP. Change `Textbox.Text` to either `i.Text` or `ListView.Items(i).Text`... whichever one doesn't throw an error. Then rerun. I think it will be illuminating.

Comment: `Textbox.text` is just what the user input for example the user input CAT and it gets added to the listview, so the messagebox would show. Are you sure you want to delete CAT , again im new to vb so sorry for the confusion i don't know a betterway to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to exit the for loop

```
Dim response As Integer

For Each i As ListViewItem In ListView.SelectedItems
    response = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete " + TextBox.Text, vbYesNo, "Confirm Delete")
    If response = vbYes Then
        ListView.Items.Remove(i)
        goto Here
    End If
Next
Here:
```

by the way, this is vb.net, edit your post with vb.net tag please.

Comment: try updated post. Does your code even work or does it still delete both items?

Comment: it's still not working. the code works it delete the item i clicked but the problem is it's deleting 2 times

Answer (score 0):

**Step1 Changing ListView1 properties following below picture**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvWq6.jpg)

**Step2 Using this code:**

```
Private Sub ListView1_ItemChecked(sender As Object, e As ItemCheckedEventArgs) Handles ListView1.ItemChecked
    Dim i As ListViewItem
    For Each i In ListView1.SelectedItems
        Select Case MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete selected record?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Confirm Delete")
            Case MsgBoxResult.Yes
                ListView1.Items.Remove(i)
            Case MsgBoxResult.No
        End Select
    Next
End Sub
```

**In my project, I use the code below (It is working):**

```
Private Sub ListView1_ItemChecked(sender As Object, e As ItemCheckedEventArgs) Handles ListView1.ItemChecked
    Dim i As ListViewItem
    For Each i In ListView1.SelectedItems
        Select Case MsgBox("คุณต้องการลบรายการขายสินค้าที่ถูกเลือกใช่ไหม", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "ยืนยันการลบรายการขายสินค้า")
            Case MsgBoxResult.Yes
                ListView1.Items.Remove(i)
                txt_barcode.Text = ""
                txt_barcode.Select()
                txt_total.Text = FormatNumber(total_price)
                txt_cost.Text = FormatNumber(total_buy)
                txt_profit.Text = FormatNumber(total_price) - FormatNumber(total_buy)
                txt_Quantity.Text = "1"
                lbl_BarcodeID.Text = ""
                lbl_Description.Text = ""
                lbl_Price.Text = ""
            Case MsgBoxResult.No
        End Select
    Next
End Sub
```